# Testing posting to forms in FunkLoad

Tags: python, testing, functional-testing, funkload

I am trying to test functionality of a web-application using FunkLoad.

The page under testing is just a login form - give email and pwd and if successful it redirects to a index page; if not successful it throws an error.

I have the below code:

```
self.get(server_url + "/login", description="Get /init/default/login")
params=[['email', 'xxxx@gmail.com'],
        ['password', 'xxxxx'],
        ['_formname','login'],
        ]
ret=self.post('%s/login' % server_url,
          params=params,
          description="Testing login functionality")

self.logd(self.getBody())
```

Whether it is a valid email id/pwd or a wrong one, the test throws a 200 as a return code and stays in the same login page.

How do I test posting in forms using FunkLoad?

(BTW, when I tested this web page with a mechanize script, I could login and then routed to the correct index page)

Thank you

Comment: could you post the complete form to see if there is something else you have to add to the POST params?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed code. I emailed the author and found out that even hidden fields should be included. It works after hidden fields are included.

Answer (score 2):

Setup the funkload proxy recorder and login into your site using your browser as described in the funkload docs: http://funkload.nuxeo.org/recorder.html

Then you easily check exactly what you are sending via POST. You might be sending other params as you think. In the following example, I am testing a django login that uses the crsfmiddleware, and also has a redirect_to param so the server knows where to redirect to if the login was successful. The test doesn't really *use* the form, it just sends what the browser would send if someone did. If you want to test real form functionality, the best way is to use something like selenium.

I had to add to extract the crsftoken manually as it changes with every request, and an assert to check that it doesn't return to a login page, but besides that, this test is just like the recorder autogenerated for me:

```
def test_LoginTest(self):
    # The description should be set in the configuration file
    server_url = self.server_url
    # begin of test ---------------------------------------------

    # /tmp/tmpMFahey_funkload/watch0001.request
    self.get(server_url + "/",
        description="Get /")
    # /tmp/tmpMFahey_funkload/watch0002.request
    reply = self.get(server_url + "/company/config/dashboard/",
        description="Get /company/config/dashboard/")

    csrftoken = extract_token(self.getBody(), "name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='", "' />")
    # /tmp/tmpMFahey_funkload/watch0005.request
    self.post(server_url + "/accounts/manager/login/?next=/company/config/dashboard/", params=[
        ['csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrftoken],
        ['redirect_to', '/company/config/dashboard/'],
        ['email', 'user'],
        ['password', '****']],
        description="Post /accounts/manager/login/")

    self.assert_("login" not in self.getLastUrl(), "Error in login")

    # /tmp/tmpMFahey_funkload/watch0008.request
    self.get(server_url + "/accounts/manager/logout/",
        description="Get /accounts/manager/logout/")
```

This works for the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='bb7d67ced4a2c6ee44eba811d44c936d' />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/company/config/dashboard/" id="id_redirect_to" />
<input id="id_email" type="text" class="formtxt fom_size1" name="email" maxlength="100" />
<input id="id_password" type="password" class="formtxt fom_size1" name="password" />
<button class="formbtn" type="submit">Validate</button>
```

Comment: I also had to change the actual "csrfmiddlewaretoken" string ... mine was "\r\r\ncsrfmiddlewaretoken".    Take out the returns in front and it worked fine.